# Python WebScraper Not Updating

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi guys so I'm creating a simple web scraper that is taking relevant articles and the dates that are shown in the headlines from cnet after searching for privacy. as shown in my code the link that it is using to pull the data, but I am having a problem. regardless of the page number that I add to the end of the url code, it is only scraping the first page. I have tested it with other urls and it pulls different data so I just don't understand why when I change the page number at the end of the URL it doesn't the specific data relevant to that page.

if possible I am trying to get it to pull data from all the pages but right now I am trying to get it to work with atleast one different page other than the main one that returns when you search for "privacy".

below is the python code

```
import urllib.request,re,webbrowser

##import MySQLdb
import cgi




##getUrl =
##getDate =
##getHeadline =
##
##cursor.execute(SQL)

def searchurl(url):

    page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    urls=page.read().decode(errors='replace')
    page.close()
    print("Searching:",url)
    ##get headers

    head = re.findall('(?<=<h3>).+?(?=</h3>)',urls)
    ##get links
    link = re.findall('(?<= <a href="/).+?\S+?(?=">)',urls,re.DOTALL)


    ##get date
    date = re.findall('(?<= <span class="assetTime">).+?(?=</span>)',urls)




    link.pop(0)
    link.pop(0)
    link.pop(0)
    link.pop(-1)
    link.pop(-1)
    for item in link:
        print(item)
    print("Header")
    for item in head:
        print(item)








url = "https://www.cnet.com/search/?query=privacy&page=3"
searchurl(url)
```

and below is the shell output

```
Searching: https://www.cnet.com/search/?query=privacy&page=3
news/the-circle-review-tom-hanks-emma-watson-tech-dave-eggers/
products/avg-privacy-glasses/preview/
news/amazon-reveals-its-newest-device-the-echo-look/
news/unroll-me-hit-with-privacy-suit-over-alleged-sale-of-user-data/
videos/tim-cook-almost-put-the-brakes-on-uber-over-privacy/
news/pause-pod-kickstarter-privacy-tent/
news/privacy-browser-brave-tor-trump/
news/microsoft-wants-you-to-trust-windows-10-privacy-again/
videos/what-is-vpn-explained-privacy-guide/
news/trump-signs-bill-repealing-us-internet-privacy-rules/
Header
'The Circle': A movie review for the tech literate
AVG Privacy Glasses
Amazon reveals the Echo Look, a device for style selfies
Unroll.me hit with privacy suit over alleged sale of user data
Tim Cook almost put the brakes on Uber over privacy
Hide from the world with your own pop-up privacy tent
Want true privacy? You need to check out this browser
Microsoft is fixing those confusing Windows 10 privacy messages
VPN explained: A privacy primer -- with robots and race cars
Trump signs bill repealing US internet privacy rules
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can confirm that the URL above will not redirect to the correct page by navigating to it via the browser directly. `https://www.cnet.com/search/?query=privacy&page=6` in a browser will take you to page 1.

Reviewing the page selectors, etc. you can see that the pagination works by using the following:
`<a class="pageno" data-pageno="2" href="/search/?query=privacy&amp;fq=&amp;sort=1&amp;p=2&amp;typeName=&amp;rpp=10">2</a>`

(You can view this using the "Inspect" tool in Google Chrome, for example.)

Adding this updated endpoint to the URL will allow us to specify the page programatically. For example, to get to page 6, use this:

`https://www.cnet.com/search/?query=privacy&fq=&sort=1&p=6&typeName=&rpp=10`

Updating your code to use this URL (specifying the page in the `&p=6`section) should fix the issue.

Comment: yes I just realized that this was the issue, it was something with the code and how it was selecting the page, thank you for your help... if I wanted it to search through say pages 1-100, would I simply create a loop and put the code inside of that?

Comment: Glad to help! That should work. I would also suggest putting a sleep for a few milliseconds in the loop to avoid hitting the site too hard.